# How to avoid hours being marked as link to calendar?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a UIWebView to fetch a webpage that contains the log of musics previous played at my radio station. The original file is [here](http://summerblast.pt/avaplayer/history_t.html). It appears on the app as follows: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TACy3.png)

How can I force it to stay with the hours in white and do not create a link to the calendar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Abizern It's not duplicate. I am not asking to disable for a specific element.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're loading it in a UIWebView you can turn off data detection for the UIWebView:

```
UIWebView *webView = // Set this up as you wish
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

This is all described in the [UIWebView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/dataDetectorTypes)